# Aligning two divs within the header to try to get a certain output

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am making a project for school where we were going to design a sort of chat app, I decided that i'd really like to make something like the discord display since it's very commonly used (skype, slack etc all look alike in some way, shape or form, thus I proceeded to make a wireframe which looks like this, https://ibb.co/KGmM7ZJ here's what I currently got, https://ibb.co/YN7wftG I know this question asks a different thing but I am also wondering how I can have black lines going the full way e.g 100% height and or 100% width depending on if it's vertical or horizontal. Thanks.

Code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <title>Dsqord</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Logo -->
    <header>
        <div class="msg-target">
            <img src="img/avatar.png">
            <h1>Mohammed</h1>
            <span class="target-status">Cool status!</span>
            <p style="font-weight: bold;">@mohammed32</p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img class="logo" src="img/logo.png">
            <br>
            <input type="search" placeholder="Search for conversations">
        </div>
    </header>

    <!-- Recent conversations -->
    <div class="recent-conversations">
        <div class="conversation">
            <img src="img/avatar.png">

            <div>
                <h3>Mohammed</h3>
                <p>Jag: Hejsan hur mår du?</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="conversation">
            <img src="img/avatar.png">

            <div>
                <h3>Mohammed</h3>
                <p>Jag: Hejsan hur mår du?</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="conversation">
            <img src="img/avatar.png">

            <div>
                <h3>Mohammed</h3>
                <p>Jag: Hejsan hur mår du?</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- -->

</body>
</html>
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0%;
    padding: 0%;
}

/* Global */


/* Header 
logo-search {
    display: flex; 
    flex-direction: row;
} */

/* Logo */
.logo {
    margin-left: 1%;
    width: 6.5%;
}

/* Input search*/
header input[type=search] {
    width: 15%;
    margin-left: 1%;
    padding: 1%;
    border: none;
}

/* Message target */
.msg-target {
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

/* Profile picture */
.msg-target img {
    width: 20%;
}


/* Recent Conversations */
.recent-conversations {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-left: 1%;
}

/* Flexbox item */
.conversation {
    display: inline-flex;
}

/* Profile Picture */
.conversation img {
    width: 5%;
}

/* Display name */
.conversation h3 {
}

/* Recent message */
.conversation p {
}
```

Comment: Do you want to align the **img/avatar.png** image with the name?

Comment: Yes I want to align the avatar.png with the name and have the status aligned with the name as well, then have the @mohammed32 under it, and have it all aligned with my logo & search however that's not the result am getting. If you can check the 2 images i've put links up for it would be very appreciated as it shows the output am looking for & my output right now.

Comment: Does the answer from @user3323829 solve your question?

Comment: No, not even remotely close.

Comment: Is it permissible to change the structure of html?

Comment: Absolutely, I don't mind it at all I really just want to be able to get the frontend done so I can work on the backend since that's what i'm best at.

Comment: Do you need such a result? - https://ibb.co/P10G3pq

Comment: Yes exactly so, I also need a line going all the way like this https://ibb.co/s6r5J6r

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the html structure a bit. Added pseudo-classes `:before` and `:after` with **absolute** positioning for displaying lines. Also, through variable `--widthLeft200px`, I made one width for the `img` and side section .recent-`conversations`.

However, I recommend using your template's design **grid**.

```css
:root {
    --widthLeft200px: 200px;
}

body {
    margin: 0%;
    padding: 0%;
}

/* Global */


/* Header 
logo-search {
    display: flex; 
    flex-direction: row;
} */

/* Logo */

header {
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
}

.logo {
    margin-left: 1%;
    width: 6.5%;
}

/* Input search*/
header input[type=search] {
    width: 15%;
    margin-left: 1%;
    padding: 1%;
    border: none;
    width: var(--widthLeft200px);
}

/* Message target */
.msg-target {
    display: inline-flex;
    /*flex-direction: column;*/
    align-items: center;
    /*justify-content: center;*/
    gap: 10px;
}

.msg-target > div {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}

.msg-target > div > h1 {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.msg-target > div:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    background-color: black;
    width: 1px;   
    top: -100%;
    left: 0;
    bottom: -100%;
    transform: translateY(0);
}

.msg-target > div:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    background-color: black;
    width: 1px;
    top: -100%;
    left: 0;
    bottom: -100%;
    transform: translateY(100%);
}

.msg-target > hr {
    width: 1px;
    height: 50px;
    border: none;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: black;
}

/* Profile picture */
.msg-target img {
    width: var(--widthLeft200px);
}


/* Recent Conversations */
.recent-conversations {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-left: 1%;
    width: var(--widthLeft200px);
}

/* Flexbox item */
.conversation {
    display: inline-flex;
}

/* Profile Picture */
.conversation img {
    width: 5%;
}

/* Display name */
.conversation h3 {

}

/* Recent message */
.conversation p {

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <title>Dsqord</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Logo -->
    <header>
        <div class="msg-target">
            <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/9d/4d/31/9d4d314ec7722d05541111a180e4e54b.png">
            <div>
            <h1>Mohammed</h1>
            <p style="font-weight: bold;">@mohammed32</p>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <span class="target-status">Cool status!</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img class="logo" src="img/logo.png">
            <br>
            <input type="search" placeholder="Search for conversations">
        </div>
    </header>

    <!-- Recent conversations -->
    <div class="recent-conversations">
        <div class="conversation">
            <img src="img/avatar.png">

            <div>
                <h3>Mohammed</h3>
                <p>Jag: Hejsan hur mår du?</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="conversation">
            <img src="img/avatar.png">

            <div>
                <h3>Mohammed</h3>
                <p>Jag: Hejsan hur mår du?</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="conversation">
            <img src="img/avatar.png">

            <div>
                <h3>Mohammed</h3>
                <p>Jag: Hejsan hur mår du?</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- -->

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     body {
            margin: 0%;
            padding: 0%;
        }

        /* Global */


        /* Header 
logo-search {
    display: flex; 
    flex-direction: row;
} */

        /* Logo */
        .logo {
            margin-left: 1%;
            width: 6.5%;
        }

        /* Input search*/
        header input[type=search] {
            width: 15%;
            margin-left: 1%;
            padding: 1%;
            border: none;
        }

        /* Message target */
        .msg-target {
            display: inline-flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
        }

        /* Profile picture */
        .msg-target img {
            width: 20%;
        }


        /* Recent Conversations */
        .recent-conversations {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            margin-left: 1%;
            height:100vh;
        }

        /* Flexbox item */
        .conversation {
            display: inline-flex;
        }

        /* Profile Picture */
        .conversation img {
            width: 5%;
        }

        /* Display name */
        .conversation h3 {}

        /* Recent message */
        .conversation p {}

        .border-bottom {
            border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
        }

        .border-left {
            border-left: 1px solid #000;
        }

    <body>
    <!-- Logo -->
    <header class="border-bottom">
        <div class="msg-target">
            <img src="img/avatar.png">
            <h1>Mohammed</h1>
            <span class="target-status">Cool status!</span>
            <p style="font-weight: bold;">@mohammed32</p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img class="logo" src="img/logo.png">
            <br>
            <input type="search" placeholder="Search for conversations">
        </div>
    </header>

    <!-- Recent conversations -->
    <div class="recent-conversations border-left">
        <div class="conversation">
            <img src="img/avatar.png">

            <div>
                <h3>Mohammed</h3>
                <p>Jag: Hejsan hur mår du?</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="conversation">
            <img src="img/avatar.png">

            <div>
                <h3>Mohammed</h3>
                <p>Jag: Hejsan hur mår du?</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="conversation">
            <img src="img/avatar.png">

            <div>
                <h3>Mohammed</h3>
                <p>Jag: Hejsan hur mår du?</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- -->

</body>

</html>
```